# P4.NET - How to list user's workspaces?

Tags: c#, .net, perforce

I am not an expert in P4.NET plugin, but I would like to show the existing workspaces for a user in a combo box, so that I can set the p4.Client to the selected workspace.

```
using (var p4 = new P4Connection())
            {
                p4.Connect();
                ???               
            }
```

How do I get the list of existing workspaces?
I think the command line to achieve this would be

```
p4 clients -m 100 -u username
```

Comment: What options does Intellisense give you at `p4.`? You want something like `Workspaces` but I don't have the code installed here.

Comment: If it was so obvious I would have slapped myself. ;) There is no Workspaces. Only p4.Client that is meant to capture a single workspace.

Comment: What other methods etc. are available? I tried to get onto http://p4dotnet.sourceforge.net/ but I'm getting a 500 error code.

Comment: lol, true I get the same error code. This APi is truly amazingly supported ;) 
Method: Connect(), ConvertDate(), CreatePendingChangelist(), Fetch_Form(), IsServerCaseSensitive(), IsValidConnection(), Connect(), PrintBinary(), PrintStream(), PrintStreamEvents(), PrintText(), Run(),  RunUnParsed(), Save_Form()

Comment: Properties: Api, CallingProgram, CallingVersion, Charset, Client, CWD, ExceptionLevel, Host, MaxLockTime, MaxResults, MaxScanRows, Password, Port, ServerLevel, TicketFile, User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have no choice than answering my own question, because the code would be too much to insert as comments to jhwist answer. Sorry jhwist. I had no choice.

@appinger, I hope you find this answer helpful. Took me hours to figure out this api working. :)

cmbBoxPerforceWorkspaceLocation is just your combobox for your workspaces. I am using Winforms by the way.

I need to extract a shortname from the windows username. Windows username starts usually with xxxx\\username.  In my code I extract the username out of the longname and save it as shortname.  If your network is set differently this code might have to change accordingly.

Let me know if it worked for you.

```
using (var p4 = new P4Connection())
            {
                p4.Connect();
                var longName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
                var shortname = longName.Substring(longName.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
                var records = p4.Run("clients", "-u", shortname);

                cmbBoxPerforceWorkspaceLocation.Items.Clear();

                foreach (P4Record record in records.Records)
                {
                    cmbBoxPerforceWorkspaceLocation.Items.Add(record["client"]);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

If P4.Net behaves similar to the official Perforce APIs, then you would likely want to run:

```
p4.Run("clients", "-m 100 -u username")
```

or similar. Inspired by the [P4Ruby](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.2/manuals/p4script/01_ruby.html#1053521) documentation.

Comment: Its actually p4.Run("clients", "-m 100 -u username"). But thanks you got me in the right direction.

Comment: Fixed in the answer. Glad it helped.

Comment: I have added some more c# Code to make it more clear. The API is not intuitive at all. It has cost me so much time. Hope my update helps someone else.

Comment: @Kave: The normal protocol is to stick it in comments and have the author do the editing in in their own words OR add your own riffing answer (which is why the edit was rehjected)

Answer (score 0):

P4.Net is designed to be similar to the scripting APIs, which in turn are designed around the command line interface.  It definitely does not have a intuitive object-oriented interface... which is off putting at first.  But if you start from the command-line (esp -ztag flag) and piece together all data/actions your app needs, you will find it pretty easy to use P4.Net.  And since it's similar to all the scripting APIs, you'll find it natural to pickup Python or Ruby if you wish :-)